# Check if any inputs are focused or active not in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't use a form in this situation, but I have a group of inputs elements. I have a table row and each td is an input. Once one loses focus I want to check to see if any others are active, if not i want to run some code.

js

```
$(document).on("blur", ".table-row", function(e) {
    var $tr = $(e.currentTarget),
        $inputs = $tr.find("inputs);

    $inputs.each(function(input) {
    $tr[input].is(":focus");
    });
});
```

The idea is I'm creating an edit form. I want to make the that once the form is done being edited I will render some different html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will check it using $('.table-row input:focus').length. If length is 0, there isn't a focused input.

But if you check it immediately after the event was fired, you'll never get it right, because the event fire just after the input blur, but before the other input gains focus.

So, you can wrap your evaluation in an instant timeout. It'll fire after 0 seconds, but after other synchronous code has been executed.

```js
$(document).on("blur", "input", function(e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ($('input:focus').length) {
           console.log(true);
        } else {
           console.log(false);
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Can you explain a little more why setTimeout of 0 seconds works?

Comment: setTimeout(f, 0) is commonly used in cases like this one. The minimum interval is 4ms, so this won't run instantly, but after other stuff (in this case, event dispatch and browser reflow). There's a proposal to "formalize" this method by implementing [setImmediate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate) but it looks like it's not going anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tabIndex to all the element of DOM and on focus change you can check whether it is last tabINdex value or not, if is it that so then render some another HTML that you want to